# Какой предлог правилен - "до" или "к" (новых впечатлений и ярких эмоций)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Душа женщины всегда голодна до новых впечатлений и ярких эмоций. Нам также важно насыщать себя красотой и уютом. Разными вкусами. Красивыми видами. Теплыми разговорами. Ароматными цветами.*

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, оба варианта одинаково нормативны, вернее сказать - одинаково разговорные, но вариант с "до" более современный.

В нормирующих источниках указаний на правильное управление найти не удалось. Это означает, видимо, что обе формы носят не более чем разговорный характер и поэтому можно иметь собственный подход к пониманию правильности.

В Нацкорпусе есть единичные бесспорные примеры употребления "голодный до" (все - современные и стилистически свободные) и только один "голодный к". Но какой!

> Обнажилась земля, голодная к севу, насытить утробу ее, разверстую,
>   ждущую… чем? [И. А. Новиков. Жертва (1921)]

Трудно делать вывод по одному случаю, но уж очень характерное значение, совсем не современное. Голодный к (чему-то) = ждущий (чего-то), **(тяготеющий к чему-то).** И в таком значении сразу пропадают сомнения в его стилистической правильности вообще и предлога в частности.

Похоже, это понимание слово "голодный" утратилось со временем (в современных словарях его нет, не знаю, было ли раньше), и заменилось современным (давно не получавший, **жадный до чего-то**). Вот предлог и поменялся.

Если все так, то в вашем случае ***"голодный до"*** получается более уместным. Причин же ни закреплять один или оба варианта, ни запрещать, сводить к просторечиям, я не вижу.

Что же до "голодный по", то мне оно не нравится. Оно требует понимания наподобие "голодный = скучающий по", а оно в слове "голодный" не прослеживается. Впрочем, это немного спорно, потому что "скучать" и "ожидать" - частичные синонимы, хотя и слабые. Но тут уже только собственное языковое чутье выручит. Моё - против.

Answer (score 1):

Душа женщины всегда голодна до новых впечатлений и ярких эмоций. Нам также важно насыщать себя красотой и уютом. Разными вкусами. Красивыми видами. Теплыми разговорами. Ароматными цветами.
Я бы написала "всегда ЖАЖДЕТ новых впечатлений...", важно "ОКРУЖАТЬ себя красотой...". По - моему, слово "голодна" с предлогами не употребляется.

Comment: В интернете (в том числе и на google books) есть немало примеров и с "голоден по", и с "голоден до". Насколько это грамотно - не знаю.

Comment: Я думаю, оба предлога (и "по", и "до")  в сочетании с данным словом несут   устаревший, отчасти книжный оттенок. А если речь идёт о нормах современного русского языка.... Вы, М_ Г., так не считаете?

Comment: Мне кажется, наоборот, это новояз. Наберите в Гугле "голоден до" и Вы увидите на спортивных сайтах "голоден до игры", "голоден до побед". Ни о каких нормах, оправдывающих такое употребление, я не знаю. Хотелось бы, чтобы профессионалы сказали свое слово.

Comment: Простите,М_Г но Гугл - это не показатель тенденции в языке. А тем более язык спортсменов.  Некоторые люди и на пальцах объясняются... Тогда уже наберите НКРЯ, и это будет аргументом. Тогда  мы продолжим разговор.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе нашел только один подходящий пример с "голоден по" : Питай свою душу подвигом [и не ожидай] и не будешь голоден по наслаждению (А. П. Платонов.). И множество "спортивных" примеров типа "голоден до побед" - только в газетном корпусе. Напрашивается вывод:  "голоден до" - новояз (возможно спортивный), "голоден  по" - скорее всего устарело.

Comment: Я Вас услышала. С "новоязом" не согласна, плохо понимаю, что это такое.Но Вы, безусловно, имеете право на собственное мнение. Спасибо за общение.

Comment: И Вам спасибо :)

Comment: Можно вмешаться? *Гугл - это не показатель тенденции в языке* - это не совсем так, выводы о *тенденциях* делать вполне можно, особенно если речь идет об интернет-библиотеке гугла, где собраны очень многие издания; штука это достаточно репрезентативная. А вот характеристику *"новояз"* - да, тут лучше не употреблять из-за её негативных коннотаций. Означает оно некий язык (в целом) массово испорченный лишенными языкового чутья носителями. Лучше уж "новодел" - недавно появившееся слово, в том числе не получившее пока фиксации в нормативных словарях.

Answer (score 1):

**голодный**
**4.** *полн.ф.* Не дающий насыщения, сытости.
*(также перен.: **получать что-нибудь в недостаточном количестве**).*
[Толковый словарь русского языка, С.И.Ожегов и Н.Ю.Шведова, 1996]

Сегодня студенты по-прежнему **«голодные»**, но уже **не до роскоши, а до знаний,** в особенности знаний практических.
[**Голодные до знаний**](http://mediaspress.ru/discussion/golodnye-do-znanij1)

Интересно, что *"голодный **до**"* встречается редко, ещё реже - *"голодный **к**"*.
Чаще всего употребляется *"голоден **до**"* и не только в языке спортсменов:

*Пару раз в троллейбусе он ловил взгляд девушки и мог поручиться, что она **голодна - до любви и просто до еды.***
[**Подлинные имена бесконечно малых величин**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=GWqDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT12&lpg=PT12&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=NhrJKUyNG-&sig=VgC-g_IiJIy44dMQdmB9YGjYot0&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAhZn3zdnTAhWFiSwKHc9cBQU4FBDoAQgeMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE&f=false)

*-Перенесённые действительно голодны, Иона, - сказал Грейнджер. - Они **голодны до жизни.***
[**Восстание мёртвых**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=SBDvDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT55&lpg=PT55&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=aOduxHbXZN&sig=vr5XURh3Gm9FgyIG0xWHt4J7tsU&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0d7bztnTAhWGWywKHeJHAUw4MhDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE&f=false)

*Жители Осло **весьма голодны до больших культурных событий,** которые уже неотделимо ассоцируются с другими европейскими метрополиями...*
[**Арт-фестиваль**](https://www.burn.com/ru/ru/news/closing-an-art-festival-became-a-night-of-legend)

На порядок реже используется *"голоден **к**":*

*Лучше всего читать утром, в это время мозг наиболее **голоден к новой информации.***
[**Читать эффективно, п.8**](https://beproductive.club/efficient-reading-b891adddc170)

Мне кажется, что *полная форма **голодный*** плавно "перетекла - видоизменилась - обновилась" в языке *в краткую форму **голоден.*** И в большинстве случаев употребляется с предлогом **до**.
Я бы остановилась на том, что фраза - "душа женщины всегда голодна до новых впечатлений..." - правильна.

Answer (score 0):

**Голодный до чего-то** ― ненормативный вариант, который, может быть,  старается стать  нормативным, то есть отметиться в словаре.

**Что может помешать?**

**1) Предлог ДО уже употребляется с этим прилагательным и обозначает степень признака:**  голодный (голоден) (в какой степени)? (примеры из Нацкорпуса) - до крайней степени, до дрожи, до боли в животе, до озверения.

**2) Существует вариант "жадный до"**  ― до денег, до всего нового, до впечатлений, до знаний, до власти, нормативный, с высокой частотностью, употребляется в текстах разного стиля.

**Жадный до всего,** что блестит, и не утоливший этого своего чувства, он нежно погладил кинжал по плоскости лезвия. [Владимир Войнович.2000].  Режиссеры народ **жадный до хорошего** и хитрый на творчество. [Алла Сурикова.  (2001)]

**3) существует вариант  "охочий до"** с таким же значением, но нар.-разг. стиля (также со значением иронии употребляется в публицистике):

**До сладенького куска охочи**, а работу ненавидят всеми фибрами души. [А. И. Куприн. (1904)] Ишь, **на дармовщину-то** все вы **охочи**. [Борис Можаев. (1966)] Люди безвременья вообще **охочи до** скандалов и сенсаций... [Николай Крыщук.  2001]